# Getting dates from a database table that fall within the current week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

What I'm trying to do is get some activities from an activity calendar that fall within the current week to create a widget that shows activities for the current week. Now how could I do such a thing with PHP/MySQL? Each database row has a date field.

This is the structure of the db table I'm working with:
[image: a busy cat]

I hope my question is clear and I hope someone will be able to help me out.

Comment: Which column is your date field? Typically, when storing dates, you would use a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column.

Comment: What is current week for you? Week number? From/to dates?

Comment: Actually week number would be better. I'll convert the datum column to a DATETIME.

Comment: Does the "current week" start on Sunday or Monday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [YEARWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function: `WHERE YEARWEEK(NOW()) = YEARWEEK(datum)`

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach will return the same value for two dates on the same week that fall on separate years, such as `SELECT YEARWEEK('2013-12-30') AS monday,YEARWEEK('2014-01-01') AS weds` regardless of the `mode` selected (which is otherwise important to correctly determine which week Sunday falls on).

Answer (score -1):

```
select foo, bar from mytable where STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%Y/%m/%d') > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS);
```

EDIT: add string to date conversion as original field is a varchar.

Comment: Sor my query would look someting like this?: select * from "agenda" where "datum" > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS);

Comment: datum is a varchar so you must convert.. `code` STR_TO_DATE(datume, '%Y/%m/%d')

Comment: I just did. So now it should work?

Comment: @FrankKluyt - you tell me, I cannot test this.  What is the format of you datum field?

Comment: I converted to a DATE field. This seems to work just fine. But is there also a way to get the current week by weeknr?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html -- I think you want WEEKOFYEAR()

Comment: @FrankKluyt - Leonid's answer is very concise and reliable